# Increase search relevance based on star-rating

Tags: php, mysql, search, rating

I'm building an application in PHP with MySQL where users can post articles and they also can rate those with a 5-star system. I've been thinking that I should move the high-rated a little bit to the top when the user perform a text search, so better articles will be easily found.

I'm using the MySQL `FULL TEXT` index to perform the search, so the relevance score come from that search.

I wonder how I could use the star-rating to tamper with the search relevance (without frustrating the user)?

I though in doing simple multiplication to raise the relevance *rating* times. That would make 5-star articles 5 times more relevant than 1-star, like this:

```
SELECT *, (MATCH (title, tags, content) AGAINST('search terms')) *
   rating AS score
 FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title, tags, content) AGAINST('search terms')
 ORDER BY score DESC
```

Is that a good idea?

I also thought in multiplying the relevance by the logarithm of the rating (plus 1, to avoid decreasing relevance when the rating is below *e*), so the increase is not so high. That would also made bad rated articles having a better chance if the relevance is higher. The statement would be like this:

```
SELECT *, (MATCH (title, tags, content) AGAINST('search terms')) *
   (1 + LN(rating)) AS score
 FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title, tags, content) AGAINST('search terms')
 ORDER BY score DESC
```

Which approach I should use? Is there a better method? Or is it better to ignore user ratings and only use term relevance?

*(As a side question, what would happen to non-rated articles?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd one sounds better. 
You should definitely take user ratings into account.

What would happen to non-rated articles,
They will be at the bottom of the list of course, which is what you want right?